# Calculating call duration per week per shift

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet that's a call log list. It lists the agent who took the call, the call start time and the duration. I'd like to create a table that lists the total duration of calls per A,B, or C shift, within a given week.

The best way to accomplish this is with a table that lists A, B and C shift on the X axis and a list of dates by week on the Y axis. What I need to do is sum call duration only if the call was placed by one of the agents on-shift and the call was handled in a given date range. This is complicated by the fact that A shift has 9 or 10 agents.

Comment: We're not a script-writing service here, but we're happy to help you when you get stuck while writing a script. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You could probably use a pivot table to get the results you are looking for, but as stated above, we need to know what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. It would also be helpful to know more about how the data is laid out and what version of Excel you are using.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a PivotTable!**

End result:
[image: End Result]

1. Choose **Date** for **rows**
2. Choose **Shift** for **columns**
3. Choose **Duration** to be a **summed value**
4. Right-click on a date in the PivotTable, choose **group**, then select **days**, and enter **7** the number of days in a week. Set the start date to be the start date for the data set, and the start of a week.

Group PivotTable items:
[image: Group PivotTable items]

Grouping based on a week:
[image: Grouping based on a week]